# String '00' equals '.0' in Coldfusion ? What else?

Tags: coldfusion, duck-typing

So I noticed that ColdFusion returns `true` for the condition `'00' == '.0'`.
This is reproducible in CF 9.1 and CF 10.
I could easily work around this by adding a `find('.', foo)` condition, but this is NOT normal.

Things like this make me doubt ColdFusion. It makes me wonder why it returns true on this clearly false condition, and what other values would it consider equal?

Is there a list of values that you can't compare in Coldfusion? Or better yet, is there a solid solution to prevent this mismatching?

Comment: Are you kidding me? `'0.25' == '6A'` . Why? Because Coldfusion thinks 0.25 is a quarter of a day, and so is 6 AM. I think that a big WTF is in order here.

Comment: Try `writeDump(compare(".0", "00")==0);` CF tries to be clever and cast the values, it often does a bad job. The compare function tests equality in two strings.

Comment: I submitted this as a bug a while back, which they verified as one. It is actually documented though that they do this (Ambiguous type expressions and strings) - http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7f46.html

Comment: This certainly violates the principle of least astonishment. http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/187457/what-is-the-principle-of-least-astonishment

Comment: It is one of the down sides of using a relatively typeless language. CF is well known for its sometimes .. bizarre or *overly generous* interpretations. So if you specifically need a *string* comparison, the equals operator is not the right choice. As mentioned, to perform string comparisons, use the function designed for that: ie `compare()`.

Comment: @jan You just learned that mathematical operators should not be used with strings in ColdFusion.

Comment: You get the same result with `is` or `eq`. Unfortunately the docs are bit misleading. They imply a string comparison: *Perform a case-insensitive comparison of two values. Return True if the values are identical.*

Answer (score 0):

As haxtb pointed out, there is more info about this issue here: [Evaluation and type conversion issues](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7f46.html). It's a type conversion issue where ColdFusion tries to interpret the short string values as datetime, boolean or numeric values rather than strings. Some examples:

```
'1a'   //datetime: 1:00am
'1p'   //datetime: 1:00pm
'0.25' //datetime: a quarter of a day or 6:00am
'.0'   //boolean: false
'.0'   //numeric: 0
```

As John Wish mentioned, if you just want to do a string comparison, you should always use the [Compare](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7f84.html) or [CompareNoCase()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7f83.html) functions instead.