# Is there a way to exact match "truthy" and "falsey" values in ColdFusion

Tags: coldfusion

I recently had the need to match against two strings in ColdFusion and ran into this scenario during my loop:

```
<cfif "0" IS NOT "NO">
```

Generally during the loop it looks something like this:

```
<cfif "AM" IS NOT "BA">
```

Now both of these values were variables (I wasn't just typing it out for fun) and I was using "0" as a default value for the first variable to match against (since the second variables would never be 0) but both of these values changed in the loop I was running. I easily fixed this by setting my default value to `--` instead of `0` but I tried researching and found nothing indicating there was a way to get around the falsey nature of strings when evaluating them.

Is there no Operator or trick to match on the strings themselves and ignore their truthyness or falseyness in ColdFusion?

Comment: If you want to avoid implicit conversion, do a string comparison,. See [Compare or CompareNoCase](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-c-d/Compare.html#main-pars_text_0).Basically the same cause as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38147638/string-00-equals-0-in-coldfusion-what-else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The compare function will help you.  This:

```
writedump(compare("0", "NO"));
```

returns -1.

[This page](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7f84.html) will tell you what that means.

Comment: Odd the documentation uses `less than` and `greater than` in their results. I don't think I've ever used `compare` now I guess I have a reason to. Still a bit confused, when will it return `1`. I need it to be false and `1` would be true. What string is `greater than` another string? I guess I'd be looking for anything other than 0.

Comment: "0" is less than "NO" because 0 is ascii 48 and N is ascii 78.  Going with the sample in your question, you would be looking for a non-zero result of the compare function.

Comment: I'd love to know why you got 2 down votes but no other comments. :)

Comment: We strictly use `if compareNoCase() EQ 0` as part of our coding standards.